Limit of $\Lambda'(\lambda)$ when $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$
Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable over the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. The cumulant generating function of $X$ is defined as $\Lambda(\lambda):=\log \mathbb{E}e^{\lambda X}$ for every $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, assume that $\Lambda(\lambda)<\infty$ for every $\lambda>0$.
I am trying to prove that $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty} \Lambda'(\lambda)= \text{ess sup } X$.
I can compute $\Lambda'(\lambda)=\frac{\mathbb{E}X e^{\lambda X}}{\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda X}}$, but I don't know how to continue. Any help is welcome.

Hint: Prove two inequalities. From the formula, you can deduce that $\Lambda'(\lambda) \leq $ ess sup $X$ for all $\lambda$. For the reverse inequality, argue that if $\lambda$ is large, then the  distribution of the measure which has density with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ given by $e^{\lambda X}/\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]$ assigns low probability to ${x < \text{ess sup}X - \epsilon}$.

Thank you @ChrisJanjigian! I can see the first inequality because $\text{ess sup }X=S$ means $X\leq S$ a.s. and hence $\mathbb{E}X e^{\lambda X}\leq S\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda X}$. I'll work in the second :)
